# ¿Es posible centrar títulos en Markdown para generar pdf?

Tags: formato, markdown, texto

Estoy trabajando en un archivo R Markdown, para finalmente knitearlo a pdf (output:pdf_document).
El archivo consiste en chunks de código separados por texto con los títulos.
Puedo centrar texto común en el documento utilizando:

```
\begin{center}
Texto
\end{center}
```

Pero no puedo hacer lo mismo si se trata de un título:

```
\begin{center}
## Texto
\end{center}
```

En este caso, me salta un error: "! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode."
¿Hay alguna forma de centrar títulos? O alternativamente, de darle formato similar al de un título a texto común.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

**Editado:** Como bien dices, mi solución anterior funcionaba si el output era Markdown o HTML, pero no PDF. Para tu caso, bastará entonces con añadir esto al header (si tienes acceso a los paquetes. Si tu editor es online seguramente los tenga):

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering \emph}
---
```

**Respuesta anterior**

Markdown está basado en html, así que puedes usar html directamente así:

```
<center> <h1>heading 1</h1> </center>
```

o puedes usar CSS así:

```
h1, h2, h3 { text-align: center; }
```

En este último caso, para ejecutar el código en CSS creo que bastará así:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
   h1, h2, h3 { text-align: center; }
```
````

**Explicación**

Las palabras `h1`, `h2`, etc. corresponden a `#`, `##`, etc. Si lo haces con CSS se aplicará a todo el documento, si lo haces con html directamente sólo afectará al header que estés escribiendo en ese mismo instante.

**Referencias**

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/center-heading.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697402/how-to-center-the-title-in-r-markdown/19698219

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365417/how-to-centre-and-bold-a-heading-in-rmarkdown-and-latex

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta! Pero en este caso no he logrado centrar los títulos utilizando esos métodos. Entiendo que esto puede deberse a que mi output es pdf, y no html. Hice la prueba generando un archivo HTML en Markdown, y en ese caso sí pude centrar el título usando `<center> <h1>heading 1</h1> </center>`

Comment: Tienes razón, había comprobado mal mi solución. He editado mi solución, ahora sí me funciona.

Comment: Agregué las líneas en el header, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo. Estoy usando RStudio, y ahora tengo un par de warnings que creo refieren a esto: "LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar  has changed. Check if current package is valid." ¿Debería descargar esos paquetes (booktabs y sectsty), y dejarlos en algún directorio en particular para poder utilizarlos? Gracias!

Comment: @Natalias lo siento, soy incapaz de reproducir tu error; funciona bien en mi versión. Uso una versión online de RStudio con los paquetes preinstalados, y no puedo ayudarte en cuanto a instalación.

Comment: @Natalias warning != error.